# Matching integers in a loop in python

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, iterable

In my example code below, I want to produce an indication of whether a predefined list of numbers either matches or does not match an iterable that I'm looping through. This is a simplified example of my problem.

Unfortunately my code below does not do what I'm expecting, and probably I'm missing something simple. In my real application this is done with extremely large 1 dimensional arrays with varied output, but this demonstrates it in a simple text way that is easy to reproduce.

Maybe I should also add that I'm using Python 2.7.5.

```
match = [1, 3, 4]
volumes=10

def vector_covariates(match, volumes):
    for i in range(volumes):
        if i == match:
            print "[*]"
        else:
            print "[ ]" 

vector_covariates(match, volumes)
```

When run, it outputs:

```
 [ ]
 [ ]
 [ ]
 [ ]
 [ ]
 [ ]
 [ ]
 [ ]
 [ ]
 [ ]
```

Whereas the "correct" output should be

```
 [*]
 [ ]
 [*]
 [*]
 [ ]
 [ ]
 [ ]
 [ ]
 [ ]
 [ ]
```

Comment: Aside: `range()` returns a zero-based list, not one-based. So your result will be: `[] [*] [] [*] [*]`. If you *want* `range()` to return a one-based list, try: `range(1, volumes+1)`.

Comment: Maybe you should add `print i, match, i == match` right before your `if ` clause. Then you'll see what's wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`in`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in) not `==`:

```
if i in match:
```

As it is, you're checking the value of `i` (a number) to a list, and those two are not going to be the same!

Answer (score 3):

`i` is a `int` value, while `match` is a `list`. They will never equal to each other.

use `in` instead of `==` like this:

```
if i in match:
    print "[*]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the integer *i* against the list *match*. Of course they're not equal. Try using *in*.